# Login session in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

How to make login session in ASP.NET MVC? For example, when the system detects admin, it will go to page A, and when the system detects customer, it will go to page B. This is my current code, it is auto generate by Visual Studio with some adjustment from me. I would like to use below codes, but it is confusing on how to add login session

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

But in my previous project, I used this concept.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValidField("Email") && ModelState.IsValidField("Password"))
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StoreContext"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetLoginData", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", user.Email);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Object objUserid = dt.Rows[0]["UserId"];
                Object objName = dt.Rows[0]["Name"];
                Object objICpass = dt.Rows[0]["ICpass"];
                Object objEmail = dt.Rows[0]["Email"];
                Object objPassword = dt.Rows[0]["Password"];
                Object objRole = dt.Rows[0]["Role"];
                Object objDateRegistered = dt.Rows[0]["DateRegistered"];

                string passwordEntered = user.Password;
                string passwordFromDb = objPassword.ToString();
                PBKDF2Hash PwdHash = new PBKDF2Hash(passwordEntered, passwordFromDb);
                bool passwordCheck = PwdHash.PasswordCheck;

                if (passwordCheck == true)
                {
                    Session["UserId"] = objUserid.ToString();
                    Session["Name"] = objName.ToString();
                    Session["ICPass"] = objICpass.ToString();
                    Session["Email"] = objEmail.ToString();
                    Session["Password"] = objPassword.ToString();
                    Session["Role"] = objRole.ToString();
                    Session["DateRegistered"] = user.DateRegistered;


                    if (Session["Role"].ToString().Equals("user"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    else if (Session["Role"].ToString().Equals("admin"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return View();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: First find the roles of the user

Comment: can u elaborate?

Comment: Hi, yes, well, basically you need to know whether or not the user is admin. I don't see such logic in you code.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign roles in database.
Then do something like this:

```
if (roleid == "admin") {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
}

else if (roleid == "user") {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
}
```